# How to add data to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, datatable

I have a table in my sqlce, and I want to display 3 columns of it in a `DataGridView`.
The three columns are Number, Time, Price, and i have loaded all that data from the sqlce table to a `DataTable`. Now how to display it in the `DataGridView`?

Comment: Show your research effort by posting the code your have tried and the place it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you for just understanding, how to fill datatable to sql database.

Add the column in datagridview :

```
        dt.Columns.Add("Number",typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Time",typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Price",typeof(String));
```

But If you directly fill the datatable form database so you don't need to add the column in datatable.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection InsertCon = new SqlConnection();
        InsertCon.ConnectionString = Connection_String;

        InsertCon.Open();

        try  
        {     
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Sql Query");
            com.Connection = InsertCon;

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();


            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            sda.Fill(dt);

             dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            InsertCon.Close();
        }
```

Comment: this will not work unless you bind the columns with the `DataTable` using `DataPropertyName` property of the column.

Comment: @Junaith : Sorry for that, I am giving just example to user but In this case we are not need to add the column in data table. According to que. , user is just want to fill the datatable from database and display it. if i m wrong let me know.

Comment: Either the DataTable is filled using an adapter or manually doesn't matter. OP wants to bind the data from the `DataTable` to `DataGridView`. For that the important point is how to tell the `DataGridView` which column to bind in the `DataTable`. That is through the `DataPropertyName` property of the `DataGridViewColumn`. Without this the data will not be displayed.

Comment: @Junaith : this is very simple. If you don't want whole database bind to datatable so you need to change the sql query. ex. select Number,Price from tablename then fill the datatable from SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: Even then if you are creating columns manually you have to tell each `DataGridViewColumn` which `DataColumn` of the `DatatTable` to bind. See the documentation of [DataPropertyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It will be clear.

Comment: @Junaith : If you are creating columns manually then I am totally agree with you but In this case we don't need create column manually.

Answer (score 0):

If your `DataTable` only has these 3 columns then set the `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true` and set the `DataGridView.DataSource=YourDataTable`. The DataGridView will automatically generate the columns when you set the `DataSource`.

If you `DataTable` has additional columns other than the three you have mentioned then you have to create the three columns in `DataGridView` and bind them to the `DataTable` using the `DataPropertyName` property of the columns. See the below sample code for this scenario.

Sample Code:

```
DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

DataGridViewTextColumn col1 = new DataGridViewTextColumn();
col1.HeaderText = "Number";
col1.Name="NumberColumn";
col1.DataPropertyName = // the column name in the datatable
DataGridView.Columns.Add(col1);

DataGridView.DataSource = YourDataTable
```